# Where to obtain the uidgid file

Tags: bash, centos, documentation, uid

I was reading `/etc/bashrc` and saw the following:

```
# By default, we want umask to get set. This sets it for non-login shell.
# Current threshold for system reserved uid/gids is 200
# You could check uidgid reservation validity in
# /usr/share/doc/setup-*/uidgid file
if [ $UID -gt 199 ] && [ "`/usr/bin/id -gn`" = "`/usr/bin/id -un`" ]; then
   umask 002
else
   umask 022
fi
```

However, my `/user/share/doc` directory doesn't have any directories beginning with `setup`:

```
[vagrant@rhcse-study-vm-1 ~]$ ls /usr/share/doc/setup-*
ls: cannot access /usr/share/doc/setup-*: No such file or directory
```

How can I find or install this documentation to look at these system uid/gid reservations? The Vagrantfile I'm using to setup this machine is [here](https://github.com/bbkane/rhcse-study/blob/master/Vagrantfile), but it's a pretty vanilla CentOS 7 box and I'm not erasing anything.

### Edit

As seen in the comments to the accepted answer I had to `yum reinstall setup` to get the folder.

Comment: Any luck with `find /usr/share/doc -name uidgid`?

Comment: @DopeGhoti Nada, nor from the root dir either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most probably you don't have the RPM package 'setup' installed on your system. The mentioned file is provided by this package.

For example in case of setup-2.8.71-7.el7.noarch.rpm it is:

```
/usr/share/doc/setup-2.8.71/uidgid
```

Comment: `Package setup-2.8.71-7.el7.noarch already installed and latest version`, and it's not there

Comment: Then there is some problem with your image. I can see the file on my system and it's also listed when you search for the uidgid file on the rpm.pbone.net. Try 'yum reinstall setup'.